# How to update Solr schema using php solr extension?

Tags: php, solr, lucene

Solr allows to update the schema of a collection using the schema API as given in the link below:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html

However, the php extension for solr, (refer here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) does not seem to support updating of schema. Is there any way to update the schema using this extension?

Comment: Have you thought of updating it without the extension? It's an API so it can be modified via Curl

Comment: @meWantToLearn That is what I am doing right now. But I wanted to know if it can be done using this extension.

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to it. But ideally, the Schema shouldn't be modified many times.